# Socket.io chat application not working with express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I need debugging help in regards to my chat application. I followed instructions from an E-Book on Socket.IO but the application will not recognize any client to server/server to client interactions. No error is reported when I run my node application so I have to idea how to debug my code. The working application should be able to send client messages to the server to be displayed by all clients with a socket connection. My "www" file in "bin" runs the node server. My folder structure is as follows:

[image]

www file:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('socketio:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
require('../routes/socket.js').initialize(server);
/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

app.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});




module.exports = app;
```

public/javascripts/chat.js:

```js
var socket = io.connect('/');
socket.on('message', function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#messages').append('<div class="'+data.type+'">' + data.message + '</div>');
});

$(function(){
    $('#send').click(function(){
        var data = {
    message: $('#message').val(),
    type:'userMessage'
        };
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    $('#message').val('');
});
});
```

routes/socket.js

```js
var io = require('socket.io');

exports.initialize = function(server) {
    io = io.listen(server);
    io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(
        {type:'serverMessage',
        message: 'Welcome to the most interesting chat room on earth!'}));

    socket.on('message', function(message){
        message= JSON.parse(message);
        if(message.type == "userMessage"){
            socket.broadcast.send(JSON.stringify(message));
            message.type = "myMessage";
            socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
        }
    });
});
};
```

layout.jade

```html
doctype html
html
  block head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js')
  body
    header#banner
      h1 Awesome Chat
    block content
    footer hope you enjoy your stay here!
```

index.jade:

```html
extends layout

block append head
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/chat.js')

block content
  section#chatroom
    div#messages
    input#message(type='text', placeholder='Enter your message here')
    input#send(type='button', value='Send')
```

Comment: check if send message from browser console gets through by logging the result in the .on("message").

Comment: nothing goes through. Any clues?

Comment: the weird message "Welcome to the most interesting chat room on earth!" gets to the client when connected or not?

Comment: that message does not log to my console no. Have I messed up my routing? I feel like that is the issue.

Comment: the message shouldn't log into the console, it's sent to the client, but you can console.log something to see the result in the console. and also about the routing, where are you calling the initialize of routes/socket.js?

Comment: Please run your node application with DEBUG on like this;  DEBUG=* node yourfile.js  and paste the output where the socket connection starts to initialize. It can be a firewall issue, namespace issue etc.

Comment: I initialized my socket on www file require('../routes/socket.js').initialize(server);